# Is APNS cert same as App Store app cert?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Our product is white labeled, so while we host the backend, which will include the "provider" in APNS parlance, the App Store submission is not done by us.

Does APNS have to use the same cert as the application's App Store cert?

Answer (score 0):

APNS certificate is different from App Store cert. However, both certificates, app store and apns should be generate for same App id. i.e. you will need access to developer account on which app id is created.